# SQL Error: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS." Not sure how to fix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to get the results of a subquery into a parameter based on if the email address exists in the DB or not.  Once it's found, I want it to set the ID of the row found to @ID and delete the row.  However, I'm receiving the following error:

"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

I've searched high and low for an answer, but I'm coming up empty.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I fix it?

Feel free to leave any advice on what I could be doing better as well.  Thanks!

```
DECLARE @EmailAddr varchar(255)
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @Email_Text varchar(max)

SET @EmailAddr = (SELECT TOP 1 Email FROM tempdb.dbo.WarrantyAnniversaryEmail)
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(Email) FROM tempdb.dbo.WarrantyAnniversaryEmail WHERE Email = @EmailAddr) > 0
BEGIN

    SET @Email_Text = @Email_Text + ';' + (SELECT TOP 1 Id, [First] + ' ' + [Last] as FullName, @EmailAddr, Company, Phone, [Address] + ', ' + City + ', ' + [State] + ' ' + Zip as FullAddress
        FROM tempdb.dbo.WarrantyAnniversaryEmail
        WHERE Email = @EmailAddr)
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM tempdb.dbo.WarrantyAnniversaryEmail WHERE Email = @EmailAddr)
    DELETE FROM tempdb.dbo.WarrantyAnniversaryEmail WHERE Id = @ID
    PRINT @Email_Text
END
```

Comment: And what aspect of the error message do you not get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is obviously this line:

```
SET @Email_Text = (@Email_Text + ';' +
                   (SELECT TOP 1 Id, [First] + ' ' + [Last] as FullName, @EmailAddr, Company, Phone, [Address] + ', ' + City + ', ' + [State] + ' ' + Zip as FullAddress
                    FROM tempdb.dbo.WarrantyAnniversaryEmail
                    WHERE Email = @EmailAddr
                   )
                  );
```

The subquery selects multiple columns, starting with `id`.  A subquery used in this context is a "scalar subquery" and it can return only a single column (and at most one row).

I'm not sure what you *want* to return, so it is hard to make a more concrete suggestion.

Comment: Essentially I just want to return a string of text separated by semi colons, ordered by email, to a python script I have.

Comment: Now that I think about it, could I just return one column that contains all the columns, similar to how I concat the first and last names?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks for your advice all the same!